# KML markers have recently disappeared from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

About half a year ago I created a Google Maps application (v3) which loads a number of placemarks from a KML file ( http://www.ioors.nl/projects.kml ). This used to work without any problems. Recently though, I have noticed that the markers are not visible anymore in the map. When I load the KML file in maps.google.com the placemarks are listed on the left, but the markers aren't visible there either.

After running a few tests this problem would seem the be caused by style element. Leaving it out makes the markers visible.

I have also tested this with some sample KML code from Google ( https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle ) and the same problem seems to occur there.

Has Google Maps' support for KML changed recently (can't find anything on Google about that though) or is something else causing the problem?

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Wilco Kuyper

Answer (score 1):

Something did change recently (about 1 week ago) related to Google Maps support for KML. Right near the end of last month, there were a number of developers here on Stack Overflow with questions about the number of KML layers being limited to 5. An issue was logged on the [Google Maps Issues site](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) and it was fixed very soon afterwards. You may have run into an additional issue.

Since the problem you are seeing is also present on the Google sample code, it sounds like there is an issue. I'd double-check everything, make sure you have a true issue, and then visit the link above to submit a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your scale element is correct. The Google Maps API KML parser is now honouring it (as well as hotSpot).

Comment: could you elaborate?